# Integrating customized HTML template in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise

I have got two HTML pages from designer. One is the home page while other is inside page. I want to use it in my SharePoint 2010 site. Is there a tutorial on it? Where do I start?

Just to be clear, I want to create my own site or site collection based on this template.

I have already downloaded SharePoint designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you start with the starter master page (http://blog.drisgill.com/2009/11/starter-master-pages-for-sharepoint.html) and put the surrounding (generic) html there. Do not use the SharePoint Designer, use Visual Studio instead to create a branding package that you deploy into SharePoint. Create page layouts that put the page specific html for the start page and one page layout for the rest.

//M

Comment: Why not SharePoint Designer? Not everybody has VS, it's not free, it has a much steeper learning curve, and it requires admin server access to deploy packages. With SPD everything can be done without touching the server.

Comment: Now all good things in life is not free is it? :) It depends on the customer of course. SharePoint designer may suite the smaller company that hasn't different staging enviroments and just want to have SharePoint. But you should never develop on a production enviroment for example. And when you develop in SharePoint Designer in your dev enviroment how do you move your branding to the production in a safe way? If you build a branding package you can move it wherever you want. Upload it to the solution store or deploy it from VS. I could write a lot more about this .. no chars left ;)